# Encoding (UTF-8) issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to write to text from a list. But encoding not working & writing like bits.

```
with open('freq.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in freq:
        f.write("%s\n" % item.encode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
b'okul'
b'y\xc4\xb1l\xc4\xb1'
```

Expected:

```
okul
yılı
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8") as file:
    file.write('Okul')
    file.write('yılı')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, you can declare your desired encoding in the call to [open](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open('freq.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for item in freq:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

If you don't provide an encoding it will default to the encoding returned by [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).

The problem with your code is that `'%s\n' % item.encode('utf-8')` encodes `item` as bytes but then the string formatting operation implicitly calls `str` on the bytes, which results in the bytes' [repr](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#repr) being used to construct the string.

```
>>> s = 'yılı'
>>> bs = s.encode('utf-8')
>>> bs
b'y\xc4\xb1l\xc4\xb1'
>>> # See how the "b" is *inside* the string.
>>> '%s' % bs
"b'y\\xc4\\xb1l\\xc4\\xb1'"
```

Making the format string a `bytes` literal avoids this problem

```
>>> b'%s' % bs
b'y\xc4\xb1l\xc4\xb1'
```

but then writing to the file would fail because you cannot write bytes to a file opened in text mode.  If you really want to encode manually you would have to do this:

```
# Open the file in binary mode.
with open('freq.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for item in freq:
        # Encode the entire string before writing to the file.
        f.write(("%s\n" % item).encode('utf-8'))
```